# Run local server on codecept-nightmare in Angular Project

Tags: angular, nightmare, codeceptjs

We want to implement some basic E2E tests in our Angular 7 application with [codeceptJS Nightmare](https://codecept.io/nightmare). The tests should be part of the CI pipeline. I followed the docs and set up a *basicTest.e2e.js*:

```
Feature('Basic');

Scenario('test if Users header appears', (I) => {
    I.amOnPage('http://localhost:4200/users');
    I.see('Users', 'h1');
});
```

as well as a *codecept.json*:

```
{
  "tests": "./e2e/*.e2e.js",
  "timeout": 10000,
  "output": "./_tmptest",
  "helpers": {
    "Nightmare": {
      "url": "http://localhost",
      "show": false,
      "restart": false
    }
  }
}
```

and execute it with `codeceptjs run --steps`. However, this leads to an **error**:

```
CodeceptJS v1.3.2

Basic --
  test if Users header appears
   I am on page "http://localhost:4200/users"
  ✖ FAILED in 465ms


-- FAILURES:

  1) Basic
       test if Users header appears:
     navigation error

  Scenario Steps:

  - I.amOnPage("http://localhost:4200/users") at Object.obj.(anonymous function).obj.(anonymous function) [as amOnPage] (node_modules/codeceptjs-nightmare/node_modules/codeceptjs/lib/actor.js:28:26)



  Run with --verbose flag to see NodeJS stacktrace


  FAIL  | 0 passed, 1 failed   // 1s
```

Executing the command with `ng serve` running in another console **works**:

```
CodeceptJS v1.3.2

Basic --
  test if Users header appears
   I am on page "http://localhost:4200/users"
   I see "Users", "h1"
  ✓ OK in 2173ms
```

so obviously the local server did not start before running the tests. I could not find a way to configure a *codecept* startup command, e.g. npm's [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) (as the project is already compiled at this point in the pipeline) in *codecept.json*.

**Is there a way to start a local server, then run Codecept-Nightmare E2E-Tests and terminate the server afterwards?**

I would also accept a hacky (scripting) solution (e.g. in package.json) as `ng serve && codeceptjs run --steps` does obviously *not* work.

Comment: *"the local server did not start before running the tests"* - why did you expect that it *would*? Codecept's job is to run your tests, not your server. I'd suggest using something like [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run the server and tests in parallel (a blog post I wrote on automation [here](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2019/Feb/10/automation-for-the-people.html), with links to repos which have config you could reuse). Also note that, as the base URL is set, you could just do `I.amOnPage("/users");`.

Comment: I'm using `concurrently` now and it works fine, thank you!